# Magento Basic Question throught Reading The Tutorial

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. Some questions make me crazy in the tutorial on their document.
1, How to open the development mode in magento 1.5.1?

2，"Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in D:\PHPWeb\mag\app\code\local\Magentotutorial\Weblog\controllers\IndexController.php on line 7"

It means I can not instantiate a model object. Someone help me. This is my code below.

Controller:

```
    class Magentotutorial_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {    
    public function testModelAction() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
        echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
        $blogpost->load($params['id']);     
        $data = $blogpost->getData();
        var_dump($data);    
    } 
}
```

Model:

```
class Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
    }
}
```

Config.xml:

```
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Weblog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Weblog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <weblog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
                    <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                </args>
            </weblog>
        </routers>
    </frontend> 
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model</class>
            <!-- 
            need to create our own resource, cant just
            use core_mysql4
            -->
            <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </weblog>
        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>              
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </models>
</config>
```

And my database name is blog_posts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your Mysql4 model class too?

Comment: Thank you. Acturally it needs a mysql4 model class, but you know, the Fatal error mainly means I can't instantiate a model object. That's the key problem in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my previous comment, you need the mysql4 model class to have the class "talk" to the DB throught the Magento DB Abstraction Layer.

The issue with your model instantiation should be due to the missing  tag in your config file:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Weblog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Weblog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <weblog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
                    <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                </args>
            </weblog>
        </routers>
    </frontend> 
    <global>
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model</class>
            <!-- 
            need to create our own resource, cant just
            use core_mysql4
            -->
            <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </weblog>
        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>              
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, Fabrizio. I change my config.xml to your code, but it still got a Fatal error. I really do the example according to the article at the address http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics.

Comment: Can you try to comment the constructor of Blogpost class and try again? (please remember to flush Magento cache)

Comment: Yes, I flush the cache and comment the constructor. Still not working. I really have no idea where is wrong. Have you got the successful result according to the article?

Comment: I have just tried till your code and I have a similar issue that is due to the missing mysql4 model class and configuration. Can you update the error message you get after having updated your config.xml as above? please uncomment your constructor for the Blogpost.php.

Comment: @Ruiwant - In your question the `<models>` element is not surrounded by `<global>`. Here the `<global>` element is present but perhaps you didn't notice that bit. Did you update your copy correctly?

Comment: Well, Thank you all very much. I think it's the config.xml problem mentioned by clockworkgeek. And Fabrizio had told me before. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with Magento 1.5 . For the developper mode, go to app/code/core/Mage.php,
near line 116, put $_isDevelopperMode on true. You also need to remove the comment in index.php on line 70  #ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Instead of hacking core files you can add the following to the site's .htaccess file, `php_flag display_errors on` and `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true`